# How to capture value of id from tr in jmeter using css/jquery selector?

Tags: http, jmeter, request

How to capture value of id from below code:

```html
<tr id="195">
<td style="width:12px !important;min-width:15px !important;">
<input type="checkbox" class="chkStatus" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below regEx:-

[image]

Hope this helps.